# Cakephp two databases from two different locations/domains

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've my application running on one server.
Login functionality will be for users from another database hosted on another server.
Is there any way to connect that database, check login and after login success/failure, return to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give a definite tested answer but I might be able to point you in the right direction.

In CakePHP you can have multiple database connections set.

In /app/config/database.php, add an additional database config variable. For example:

```
<?php
var $userDb = array(
    'driver'      => 'mysql',
    'persistent'  => false,
    'host'        => 'example.com', // Put the hostname of the other database here
    'login'       => 'username',
    'password'    => 'password',
    'database'    => 'other_db_name'
);
?>
```

Then, in your User model, add the following property:

```
<?php
var $useDbConfig = 'userDb';
?>
```

With this in place all of the User model's database operations should use the $userDb config details.

More info can be found in the [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/922/Database-Configuration).

Comment: I tried this, but it gives errors like Host 'comp.local.lan' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server, or A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. Even if i've set max_execution_time to 300..... Please help

Comment: This is not a problem with your PHP code. It is happening because the MySQL server that you're trying to connect to is blocking the connection. You will have to change the settings on the MySQL server to allow the host that your CakePHP app is on to connect. If you don't know how to do this you'll have to speak to the server's administrator. Or if you are the administrator of the MySQL server and don't know how to do this, search on Google or try asking on serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanx, I made these settings on host, GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO usern...@192.168.1.3
IDENTIFIED BY 'password' . Thanx for your solution.